# In JPA how to define a table column that can store either a CLOB or a BLOB

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am defining an entity that just stores document objects for the user.  Sometimes the object is a binary (BLOB) such as a PNG or JPG image, and sometimes it is character based, such as RTF text files or a MIME text/* type.  All documents have a unique ID in the same name space.  The properties are roughly like this:

```
@Id private long id;
@Column private String type;
@Lob private byte [] rawData;
```

Now I could just provide some accessor methods that would convert rawData from a byte [] to a String on demand, but is there a technique that avoids the frequent conversion step in the case of character data?  Note that I don't want the JPA provider to do it either -- I want to use one table column to store either the character data or the binary data with minimal or no transcription overhead when it is injected into the entity instance.

I think I should be able to code a base class and two sub-classes like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Document {
    @Id private long id;
    @Column private String type;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("binary")
public class BinaryDocument extends Document {
    @Column @Lob private byte [] binaryData;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("text")
public class TextDocument extends Document {
    @Column @Lob private String textData;
}
```

(omitted accessor methods for brevity)

If I understand this I would end up with a table with two @Lob columns, **binaryData** and **textData**.  Is there any way to make them the same column?

Or should I care?  Would the space requirement for having two columns (only one of which is used in each instance of the class) be minimal?

Or should I be taking a completely different approach?  I am open to suggestion since I haven't spent much time on coding this yet.

Comment: Minimize it further by using a join table aproach, where the blob is in its own blob table and the clob in a clob table.  The Doc table would then join to one of them based on the subclass type.

Comment: Well I can't think of a better solution than this.  I had thought of this and it does have the advantage of splitting your bulk storage between two tables which gives opportunities for optimization.   If you write this up as an answer I'll check it for you.